# Preload next page in ViewHolder2 like it was automatically done in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager2

How to preload next page and page before in ViewPager2? My app uses list from api in each ViewPager2 tab screen. It is good user experience when next page is loaded before user swipes to it. On old ViewPager it was done automatically

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Now it is possible in **`ViewPager2`**

Use [**`Version 1.0.0-alpha04`**](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/viewpager2#1.0.0-alpha04)

## New features

- **offscreenPageLimit:** allows for a tight control of the number of page Views / Fragments kept in the view hierarchy

## API changes

- orientation and `isUserScrollable` attributes are no longer part of SavedState
- `saveState` and `restoreState` methods made final in FragmentStateAdapter
- `ViewPager2.Orientation` and `ViewPager2.ScrollState` annotations made non-public

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
viewPager2.setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
```